# Corrupted Windows Language - how to reinstall/fix using cmd/Powershell?

Tags: windows, windows-11, language-pack

Don't ask me how exactly it happened, it just did.
Just received a new laptop for work, which was set with "pt-BR" as default locale.
Since I prefer using en-US (which helps with troubleshooting efforts, since I don't need to unlocalize anything), I've installed this new language pack and applied as current.

Now, after a Windows update, several UI elements shows with misleading/swapped labels (see images below).

[image: Swapped Labels 1]
[image: Swapped Labels 2]

Trying to fix the issue (reinstalling the language pack) following the traditional Settings UI is not possible because it crashes before I get there - probably just because of these wrong strings resolving to unexpected values.

```
Fault bucket 1447304804967042071, type 5
Event Name: MoAppCrash
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: windows.immersivecontrolpanel_10.0.6.1000_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
P2: praid:microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel
P3: 10.0.22621.900
P4: 12963a0f
P5: combase.dll
P6: 10.0.22621.900
P7: 622991f2
P8: 802b000a
P9: 00000000000918bb
P10: 
---
Faulting application name: SystemSettings.exe, version: 10.0.22621.900, time stamp: 0x12963a0f
Faulting module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll, version: 10.0.22621.963, time stamp: 0x89a1dc34
Exception code: 0xc000027b
Fault offset: 0x0000000000870210
Faulting process id: 0x0x475C
Faulting application start time: 0x0x1D92F57F6DC05EC
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
Report Id: a5ddd587-71f0-4058-ab4f-db2b22d3c698
Faulting package full name: windows.immersivecontrolpanel_10.0.6.1000_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Faulting package-relative application ID: microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel
```

```
Windows Version: 22H2
OS Build: 22621.1105
```

What to do?
Or should I resign and fresh install everything?

### Update 1

These commands were already run and nothing wrong found:

```
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
sfc /scannow
```

Comment: Start by testing Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html) and finally reboot.

Comment: Sorry - forgot to mention that. Steps already run and no corruption found.

Comment: Next step is to do [Repair Install Windows 11 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/). This will conserve all apps, user data, and most settings. It's the same as doing a major Windows upgrade, so take the same precautions. It will set Windows to a consistent state.

Comment: I assume you can't just delete the effected user profile off the machine and recreate it?

Comment: @harrymc - Your suggestion to a user of an laptop owned by a Enterprise is to reinstall Windows?

Comment: @Ramhound: No, to upgrade it to the latest Windows version (even if this same version is already installed). If Settings itself is crashing, something is very very wrong.

Comment: @harrymc - I suspect the profile is simply corrupt likely connected to the image that was used to install Windows.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. I'm trying to manually download and reapply a language pack (pt-BR, in this case) thru command-line using `DISM` and `lpksetup`. If it doesn't work, I'll try to repair the installation (unfortunately it didn't gave me the option to keep installed apps/features).

Answer (score 1):

OK, it seems that my English language pack is indeed corrupted.
The conventional solution would be going to a repair or fresh install.

Alternatively, though, I was able to reinstall and switch my user language preference to `pt-BR` again using powershell.

[Powershell new languages installation commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/languagepackmanagement/install-language)

[Powershell regional settings available commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international)

```
(using elevated powershell prompt)

   Install-Language "pt-BR"
   Set-WinUILanguageOverride
   Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList (New-WinUserLanguageList -Language "pt-BR") -Force
```

Note: Uninstalling and reinstalling back the `en-US` language package still incurs in the same problem (seems that the corrupted package may be in cache somewhere).